# Print hash of arrays with commas between the elements of the array

Tags: arrays, perl, csv, hash

I am using

```
  for $fields ( sort {$a<=>$b} keys %HoA) {
       print "$fields-->@{$HoA{$fields}}\n";
   }
```

to print my hash. The output is:

```
0-->2132123 321321321 ABCDEFG 32 DEF ...
```

I would like:

```
0-->2132123,321321321,ABCDEFG,32,DEF,...
```

Is there a way to alter the print statement to give me the commas? I would rather not use anything like `s/ /,/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an explicit [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html).

```
for $fields ( sort {$a<=>$b} keys %HoA) {
    print "$fields-->" . join (',', @{$HoA{$fields}}) . "\n";
}
```

or localize a version of the $LIST_SEPARATOR per [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

```
for $fields ( sort {$a<=>$b} keys %HoA) {
    local $" = ',';
    print "$fields-->@{$HoA{$fields}}\n";
}
```